# How do I prevent a jQuery handler on a button element inside a form from executing when the user presses enter?

Tags: jquery, html, forms, button, form-submit

I have a `button` element inside a `form` like this:

```
<form>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Test</button>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

With the following JS:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
    alert('Form submitted.');
    return false;
});

$('button').click(function() {
    alert('Button clicked.');
});
```

And the jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JnnRX/

When the user focuses the text field, types in some text, and presses enter, the `button` handler will execute first, followed by the `form` handler. However, I'd like it to just 
execute the form handler and ignore the button. Is there any way to get this behavior, or is it best to change my `button` element to something else?

Comment: Why are you wanting a button inside a form? There might be another way around this.

Comment: The button is used to pick a template from a modal dialog that pops up when it's clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the button of type `button`

```
<button type="button">Test</button>
```

If it is that type, the browser won't recognize "enter" submits, unless that button has focus. Typically the first `submit` button in a form's flow will be the one to get submitted on enter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the easier way in my case is just to change it to another element altogether, like `<span class="button">`.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/JnnRX/17/

Basically you just use e.preventDefault() on keyup() for the form. e represents the keyup event, and e.keyCode represents the key that was pressed. 13 is the enter key's keycode.

EDIT:
Woops, I didn't understand your original request. I've updated the jsfiddle with what you wanted.